# Adding multiple elements to String[]

Tags: java

In my main method I have the command below:

```
if (args.length == 0) // if no command line argument is given
    args.addAll(Arrays.asList("Hello","world"); // error
```

And there's an error says:

> Cannot invoke addAll() on the array type  String[]

How do I add multiple elements to `args`?

Comment: You're missing a bracket to close `args.addAll(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you cannot do such a thing. To append elements to array (not `ArrayList` or other Collections), create new array and copy elements in old array and elements to append.

In this case, you can simply assign new array with default elements like this:

```
if (args.length == 0) // if no command line argument is given
    args = new String[]{"Hello","world"};
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you're trying to invoke is used by the List objects, not arrays.
If you want to work with List, which is easier to use when it comes to add data, try :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
list.addAll(Arrays.asList("Hello","world"));
```

This method will happen them no matter what. if you only want to append them if ags is empty, then use

```
if (args.length == 0) // if no command line argument is given
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList("Hello","world"));
}
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work.  [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) returns a List *backed* by an array;  you cannot add to it or remove from it.  But you can do `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(args))`.  Also, [Collections.addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-) is preferred over addAll(Arrays.asList(…)).

Comment: Oh, okay, editing that. Didn't know about it, and it somehow didn't show any error in my IDE, thanks

Comment: I am accepting Mike's solution since it does not require an additional `List<String>` object, but thanks.

Comment: No problem, I agree with you on that one. I didn't see immediatly that args was supposed to be empty. His answer fits the problem, mine doesn't